# Service Reference showing as folder in Visual Studio 2010 in Windows 8.1

Tags: .net, windows, visual-studio-2010

I am using Visual Studio 2010 with Window 8.1 and on the reference menu I am unable to find Add Service Reference

[image]

Have anyone faced similar issue when using VS 2010 on Windows 8.1

Answer (score 0):

I just removed the whole solution and get an update from my SVN repository. Removing and getting a new instance of the solution brings service reference in a proper form.
I am using VS 2010 as Administrator privileged in Windows 8.1